How to create a ObjectOwner(not AddressOwner) object in sui move?
// Copyright (c) Mysten Labs, Inc.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

/// This example demonstrates a basic use of a shared object.
/// Rules:
/// - anyone can create and share a counter
/// - everyone can increment a counter by 1
/// - the owner of the counter can reset it to any value
module counter::counter {
  /// A shared counter.
  public struct Counter has key, store {
    id: UID,
    owner: address,
    value: u64
  }

  
  public fun create_and_transfer_counter(contract_address: address, ctx: &mut TxContext) {
    let counter = Counter {
      id: object::new(ctx),
      owner: ctx.sender(),
      value: 0
    };
    // 使用 transfer::transfer_to_address 将计数器的所有者设置为当前合约地址
    transfer::public_transfer(counter, contract_address);
    }
}


create_and_transfer_counter create and AddressOwner Object event I pass contract_address as a object id. So How to create a ObjectOwner object in sui move.


You can directly transfer the Child to the Parent object.

    // Sui Version: 2024.beta
    public struct Child has key, store {
        id: UID,
    }

    public struct Parent has key {
        id: UID,
        child: Option<Child>,
    }

    public fun create_parent(parent: Parent, child: Child) {
        transfer::transfer(child, parent.id);
    }

You can retrieve the Child object using the suix_getOwnedObjects function of the Sui API. However, you cannot determine if the Parent object has a Child object in Move.

You can set the Child object as an option field of the Parent object.

    // Sui Version: 2024.beta
    public struct Child has key, store {
        id: UID,
    }

    public struct Parent has key {
        id: UID,
        child: Option<Child>,
    }

    public fun create_parent(child: Child) {
        let parent = Parent {
            id: object::new(ctx),
            child: option::some(child),
        };

        transfer::transfer(parent, tx_context::sender(ctx));
    }


You can use dynamic_fields, ObjectBag or ObjectTable.

